# Pointer character array works, but when printed outputs the wrong characters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character

Ok now this isn't imperative for my goal in getting this program to work, but I don't understand why it's storing strange characters into the array in place of the characters typed into the terminal.

Here is what I get when I run the program...

Enter a message: He lived as a devil, eh?

HE  ( ╠ ( ═▓!u ·ñΣ■   jX

Palindrome

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 21.120 s
Press any key to continue.

---

Enter a message: Madam, I am Adam.

MADAM,╠ ( ═▓!u┴:»

Not a palindrome

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 9.039 s
Press any key to continue.

As you can see it works ^....

```
    // Chapter 12 Programming Project #2

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    #define N 50

    bool chk_msg(char message[],char *j);

    int main(void)
    {
        char msg[N], *p;
        int chk = 0;

        printf("Enter a message: ");
        for (p = &msg[0]; p < &msg[N];) {
            *p = toupper(getchar());
            if (((int)*p >= 65) && ((int)*p <= 90)) {
                p++;
            } else if (*p == '\n')
                break;
            printf("%c", msg[chk++]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        if (chk_msg(msg, p))
            printf("Palindrome\n\n");
        else
            printf("Not a palindrome\n\n");

        return 0;
    }

    bool chk_msg(char msg[], char *j)
    {
        char *i;
        bool palindrome = true;

        for (i = &msg[0], j--; i < &msg[N]; i++, j--) {
            if (i == j)
                break;
            else if (*i != *j)
                palindrome = false;
        }

        return palindrome;
    }
```

Comment: Another nice example on how not initialising variables could lead to massive irritation. Hint: C-"string"s need to be zero terminated, so it a good idea to fill buffers to be used as such with `0`s prior to working with them: `char msg[N] = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use [`isupper`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/isupper.html) or [`isalpha`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/isalpha.html) to check for upper case or alphabetic characters.

You get strange characters, because you `printf("%c", msg[chk++]);`. You increase `chk`, no matter if you inserted a character before.

When you move `printf` inside the first `if`, it should work as expected

```
if (isupper(*p)) {
    p++;
    printf("%c", msg[chk++]);
} else if (*p == '\n')
    break;
```

A small optimization: You can move the comparison in `chk_msg` to the `for` exit condition

```
for (i = msg, j--; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (*i != *j)
        palindrome = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @OlafDietsche, That helped a lot and was very informative. I changed all that up and it's working great now.

Answer (score 1):

You are validating the input characters with the following condition

```
if (((int)*p >= 65) && ((int)*p <= 90))
```

But in this check you are allowing only alphabets (ASCII 65 - 90), but in the input you are inputting also spaces (ASCII 0x20). This is the reason your logic goes wrong and you get garbage in the output.

If you also need spaces in your input change the condition check as follows,

```
if ((((int)*p >= 65) && ((int)*p <= 90)) || ((int)*p == 20))
```

Then everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A string in C ends with `'\0'`, the so called terminator. You never add one, so your string just runs off into random memory. Your code gets undefined behavior when dealing with that broken string.

Also, you should never hardcode ASCII values like that, use e.g. `isalpha()` to filter.

Comment: Thanks for this information, really appreciate it. I forgot about isalpha(), as I have only used it twice through-out this book

Answer (score 0):

Your message reading function is a big mess:

This works:

```
for (p = &msg[0]; p < &msg[N];) {
    char c = toupper(getchar());

    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) {  // filter out anything not between A and Z
        *p++ = c;
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    else if (c == '\n') {
        *p = 0 ;              // put the zero terminator
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

And your `chk_msg` is also wrong and overly complicated.

This is a corrected version:

```
bool chk_msg(char msg[], char *j)
{
    char *i;

    for (i = &msg[0], j--; i < j; i++, j--) {
       if (*i != *j) {
         return true ;
       }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again everyone for your input and help

```
    // Chapter 12 Programming Project #2

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    #define N 50

    bool chk_msg(char message[],char *j);

    int main(void)
    {
        char msg[N] = "", *p;
        int chk = 0;

        printf("Enter a message: ");
        for (p = &msg[0]; p < &msg[N];) {
            *p = toupper(getchar());
            if (isalpha(*p)) {
                p++;
                printf("%c", msg[chk++]);
            } else if (*p == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        if (chk_msg(msg, p))
            printf("Palindrome\n\n");
        else
            printf("Not a palindrome\n\n");

        return 0;
    }

    bool chk_msg(char msg[], char *j)
    {
        char *i;

        for (i = &msg[0], j--; i < &msg[N]; i++, j--) {
            if (i == j)
                return true;
            else if (*i != *j)
                return = false;
        }
    }
```